# Use JSON String in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, json

I created a JSON string using JSON.NET.

using following code

```
  public void JSONTable()
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=INBDQ2WK2LBCD2S\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MCAS;Integrated Security=SSPI");
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select top 10 x,dt from test4 order by Id desc", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);

        string DATA = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, new Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting());

    }
```

The JSON looks like

`[{"x":"0","dt":"11/21/2013 3:07:53 PM"},{"x":"0","dt":"11/21/2013 3:07:52 PM"},{"x":"0","dt":"11/21/2013 3:07:50 PM"},{"x":"0","dt":"11/21/2013 2:47:21 PM"},{"x":"0","dt":"11/21/2013 2:47:20 PM"},{"x":"0","dt":"11/21/2013 2:20:02 PM"},{"x":"188","dt":"11/20/2013 11:46:53 AM"},{"x":"188","dt":"11/13/2013 11:31:38 AM"},{"x":"188","dt":"11/13/2013 11:31:26 AM"},{"x":"188","dt":"10/31/2013 2:49:27 PM"}]`

Now how can I use this JSON String `DATA` into Javascript?

And How can I create a physical file with `.json` extension?

Comment: Where and how you want to use this data?

Comment: Well I want to use this for creating either google chart or highchart.

Comment: <script>var DATA = <%= DATA %>;</script>

Comment: And use [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON) javascript API to work with DATA.

Comment: @Enam: It gives the error that` DATA does not exists in the current context`

Comment: @Saumil backend string DATA must be public.

Comment: @Enam : Where should I declare it exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need onload object:

You may create in your code-behind global public string variable with valid JSON:

```
public string DATA;
```

After that create js variable to use it in your client code:

```
var jsDATA = <%= DATA %>;
```

If your JSON was valid no JSON.Parse is needed.

Comment: Pls see my edited code, it is still showing the error that `Data does not exist in current context`

Comment: To use variable in **.aspx** you must declare it as public attribute of your main class (not in local scope in method `JSONTable()`).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `json` data stored as a string and you want to get an object in JS - use `$.parseJSON(yourStringJSON)` from **jQuery**. Another option (I prefer it) is to use `JSON.parse(yourStringJSON)`.
Both methods return json object.